# Is there any tool to validate @XmlPath annotations?

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Is there any tool to validate @XmlPath annotations used from  MOXy JAXB at a specific xml file at compile time from Eclipse or IntelliJIdea java framework or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There is no corresponding IDE tooling yet.  You could use the [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) JAXBContext to generate an XML schema and then use it to validate the XML document.

For more information of XPath based mapping an @XmlPath see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

**UPDATE**

The [**Dali**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) team is adding this support in the upcoming Juno release of Eclipse.  You can try this out today:

- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junom6

Answer (score 1):

Dali added this to Eclipse in the Juno release. You get content assist and validation on `@XmlPath` annotations among others.
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.4.0/NewAndNoteworthy/jpt.php